# Create a vector of 3 billion elements of uint8

Tags: c++

My code reads data from binary files into a uint8_t vector, when I tried to read a 3GB file of 3 billion element in the vector it failed. I get a  (std::length_error at memory location...), I am sure now it is because of the very large data size since vector.max_size is around 2.15 billion. But 3GB of data is not that large, Is there a way to store this data size into the vector?

Comment: Well, a `std::vector` guarantees a contiguous block of memory. So likely that is an issue with what you are doing here. Perhaps a better solution would be to split the data out into two d vectors? `std::vector<std::vector<uint8>>`

Comment: do you really need to load the whole giant 3GB file to memory? Look again at your algorithm

Comment: "3GB of data is not large" - oh, 2019!

Comment: Are you compiling to a [32bit target](https://godbolt.org/z/5Krq7l)? If `vector::max_size()` is "around 2.15 billion" you can't fill  it with 3GB of data.

Comment: @cplusplusrat I created 3D, 2D and 1D uint8_t vectors and tested the max size (i.e. `vec3.max_size()*vec3.at(1).max_size*vec3.at(1).at(1).max_size`  ... and so on). This is what I get: 
3D vec =~ 2.68 billion, 2D vec =~1.88 billion, 1D vec =~ 2.15 billion. 
I am not sure why the 2D vector contains the least number of elements?!!

Comment: @phuclv  , yes I do. Actually, I am reading the same file with Matlab. But it is slow, the corresponding c++ code is much faster but can not read this size !!!

Comment: It's extremely rare that you actually need to read such a huge amount of data to memory. Most of the time it's the use of a simple algorithm instead of better solutions such as sparse arrays or dynamic programming. And vector of vectors are **not** actually multi-dimensional arrays but [jagged arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array) where each element is stored separately which is slow (due to another of indirection and bad cache locality) but doesn't require a huge contiguous free memory region. It's not easy to obtain a contiguous 3GB block unless your PC has a lot of memory

Comment: What I found now that by changing the project properties , from configuration manager (I hope this is what Bob meant),  to compile to 64bit as @Bob__ suggested increased the max size of vectors dramatically (e.g. 1D vector ~= 9.22e18 elements) . I can now read the 3GB file in a single vector.
@ phuclv I do divide the data into partitions later for processing, but initially reading the whole file is important to be able to partition it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to `new` that many bytes? You may not have enough free contiguous virtual memory. Typically page size is `0x1000`, or `4096`, bytes. This means your 3 billion bytes, or `3 GB`, will require more than `732,000` pages of contiguous virtual memory availability for the full `3 GB` required. A better option would probably be to allocate them in huge blocks and build a linked list. You could also use another container that doesn't require contiguous memory or link several vectors together.

Comment: Since I am using vectors, which dynamically allocate memory, I am not using new at all.

Comment: You said you're using a single vector, it doesn't make any difference if you're calling ``new`` manually, the STL will allocate memory on the heap as needed. The point of my question was to determine if your system even has the available contiguous memory for that many bytes.

Comment: Physical memory limits don't particularly matter here. Virtual memory does not need its associated physical pages (i.e RAM) to be contiguous, and in fact it rarely is. Also if you run out of physical memory then the OS will simply resort to paging, which means physical memory will get paged out to disk and replaced when needed. In your case you *do* need it to be contiguous virtually, which means you need at least 3GB of free contiguous virtual memory in your process address space.

Comment: The absolute upper limit for an x86 process is only 4GB of virtual memory, but it will only be available if you're on an x64 OS. Note that every single user mode process also reserves a portion for the OS (usually this is lower 2GB used for the process and upper 2GB for the OS). If you're on an x64 OS then your x86 process will have the full upper limit of 4GB because there's so much more availability. If you're on an x64 process in an x64 OS then the upper limit is a whopping 8TB.

Comment: To put simply -- if you're on an x86 OS you won't have room, x86 process on x64 OS you *probably* won't have room, x64 process on x64 OS you will *absolutely* have room.

Comment: Given your ``max_size()`` reported as 2.15 billion, it certainly sounds like you're using an x86 process. That's actually almost exactly the full availability of ``2GB`` alotted to user mode on an x86 OS, as mentioned earlier. Of course this could also be an x64 OS with only 2GB of free contiguous memory, but either way it's definitely an x86 process. Compiling it as x64 should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Pickle for your illustration although it will take me time to fully understand it. But yes, compiling it as x64 did solve the problem as I mentioned in the comments. So, thanks again for you and @Bob__.

Comment: No problem, if you have any other questions at all or want a more simplified explanation of anything in particular then feel free to ask.